# Read environment variables in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, environment-variables

I have set some environment variables in `~/.profile`:

```
SOMEVAR=/some/custom/path
```

and already did `source ~/.profile`. So when I do:

```
echo $SOMEVAR
```

it prints the correct directory:

```
/some/custom/path
```

However, when I try to read this variable in a Python script, it fails:

```
import os

print(os.environ["SOMEVAR"])
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "environment_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    print os.environ["SOMEVAR"]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'SOMEVAR'
```

What's wrong there?

Answer (score 4):

You don't want the launched processes see all the crap (= variables) you've created. Hence regular variables are only visible in this shell you're executing.

You have to export the variable:

```
export SOMEVAR=/some/custom/path
```

Comment: In `~/.profile`? But why is `echo $SOMEVAR` working then?

Comment: The variable is present in your shell (the process which sourced .profile) but it is not exported to child processes  (your python script).

Comment: Wonderful, thank you for the explanation! I added the `export` and it works now :)